# How to throw b2body with various speed at fixed position?

Tags: physics, box2d, physics-engine

[image]

Above image is for ref to better representation.

I have box2d object and i know start point & end point position.

Now i want to give any force or impulse such that b2body will first collide at end point BUT with different speed also should collide at that same end point.

How should i achieve this?

Comment: You should write the physics equation of your object and solve them. I guess it is something you do in class around 11th grade?

Comment: @realUser404 Kinematic equations aren't thaught until 11th, yeah, but you should be able to do them after 10th

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a gravity force `g` (m/s²). The horizontal speed doesn't change, so you first need to calculate the amount of time it reaches the target horizontally:

```
t = distanceX / speedX
```

The object need tk reach the target in the same time vertically too. We will have a speed of `vY` (m/s) at start and `vY - g * t` (m/s) at the end vertically (positive speed goes upwards). The average vertical speed is

```
vAvg = (vY + vY - g * t) / 2 = vY - g * t / 2
```

This average speed needs to be so big, that the object would reach the target position in time t if there's no gravity

```
vY - g * t / 2 = distY / t
```

You should be able to get the starting upwards velocity by adding `g * t / 2` to `distY / t`

So, together, to get the vertical speed vY, you need to do:

```
t = distX / vX
vY = distY / t + g * t / 2
```

Comment: Keep in mind, box2d is not deterministic. You'll get some pretty accurate behavior using these equations, but it will never be exactly repeatable or exactly the same on different devices.